# Too Many Constructor Args for Dependency Injection/Inheritance Design Pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, dependency-injection

So I decided to use the Factory Design Pattern along with Dependency Injection.

```
class ClassA
{        
    Object *a, *b, *c;
    public:
    ClassA(Object *a, Object *b, Object *c) :
    a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
};

class ClassB : public ClassA
{        
    Object *d, *e, *f;
    public:
    ClassB(Object *a, Object *b, Object *c, Object *d, Object *e, Object *f) :
    ClassA(a, b, c), d(d), e(e), f(f) {}
};
```

Now, the problem is that classB has too many arguments for the constructor. This is a single inheritance-layer example, but when the inheritance layers start getting deeper, and when each layer-class needs more objects to be constructed, the constructor in the top layer ends requiring too many arguments in order to be made!

I know I could use setters instead of the constructor, but is there any other way?

Comment: My general approach is to avoid inheritance as much as possible, and try to keep each class focussed on a single responsibility. Could you construct `ClassA` separately, and then initialise `ClassB` with a reference to that, rather than tightly coupling them through inheritance?

Comment: Mike Seymour is right. Prefer a has-a relationship (composition) to the more tightly coupled is-a relationship (inheritance). Perhaps if you explain what you want to do, we can tell you how better to accomplish it?

Comment: I do not see any major problem with inheritance. It should be used everywhere where it is needed. It should be not abused as everything else.

Comment: @KirillKobelev: I entirely agree; it should be avoided unless it's needed.

Comment: What constitutes 'too many arguments'? When using IOC the container takes care of them and this only happens when you **abuse inheritance** or have a 'God Object' that does everything and depends on the universe.

Answer (score 6):

Setter are not recommended for such things because they result in a partially constructed object which is very error prone. A common pattern for constructing an object that requires many parameters is the use of builder. The responsibility of ClassBBuilder is to create ClassB objects. You make ClassB constructor private and allow only builder to call it using friend relationship. Now, the builder can look somehow like this

```
ClassBBuilder {
  public:
    ClassBBuilder& setPhoneNumber(const string&);
    ClassBBuilder& setName(consg string&);
    ClassBBuilder& setSurname(const string&);
    ClassB* build(); 
}
```

And you use the builder likes this:

```
ClassB* b = ClassBBuilder().setName('alice').setSurname('Smith').build();
```

build() method checks that all required parameters were set and it either returns properly constructed object or NULL. It is impossible to create partially constructed object. You still have a constructor with many arguments, but it is private and called only in a single place. Clients won't see it. Builder methods also nicely document what each parameter means (when you see ClassB('foo', 'bar') you need to check the constructor to figure out which parameter is a name and which is a surname).

Comment: This may be a bit nicer than setters, but you're effectively delaying the check for sufficient information is present to construct an object to runtime. I don't consider that an improvement over a plain constructor taking a few arguments.

Comment: If you want compile time enforcement, you can still sometimes benefit from the builder. This is the case when a class constructor take many optional parameters with default values. Then, you can use builder's setters to set these optional parameters and have build() method take all required params. This would give you compile time enforcement that all required parameters are passed but will be more readable and less error prone than a call to a constructor that takes many parameters some of them required some of them optional with default values.

Comment: I like this approach. The code for a client constructing the object is much cleaner. Although its true that you lose the compile time check, the build() function still allows for a validation check in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the C++ problems (if this can be called a problem). It does not have solution other than trying to keep the number of parameters of the ctor minimal.

One of the approaches is using the props struct like:

```
struct PropsA
{
    Object *a, *b, *c;
};

class ClassA
{
    ClassA(PropsA &props, ... other params);
};
```

This seems obvious but I did used this several times. In many cases it turns out that some group of params are related. In this case it makes sense to define a struct for them.

My worst nightmare of this sort was with the thin wrapper classes. Methods and data fields of the base can be accessed directly while all ctors has to be duplicated. When there are 10+ ctors, creating a wrapper starts to be a problem.

Comment: In most cases, it would make sense to make `PropsA` a full-fledged class by pushing related methods into it as well. Otherwise you just end up with a data structure which is not very object-oriented.

Comment: I put the requirements of the app, speed of development and clarity of the code FAR FAR ahead of the fancy stuffs of being "object oriented".

Comment: OOP is not "fancy", but it's a choice that you take or leave. I'm fine with someone just doing it the procedural way, using structs and functions, but if you're planning on using classes, it pays to put effort into doing it right, otherwise you end up in a mess where half your code is object-oriented and the rest is procedural -- I don't think that leads to much clarity.

Comment: The OOP itself is not fancy. It is a set of extremely useful methods. Only it is necessary to think what elements of this set are useful in each case first, and only after thinking use them. If something does not have reasonable methods and/or live for a short time - it should be a struct. And it is right for it to be a struct. This is not making the code less object oriented. OOP just for OOP - this is useless fancy stuffs.

Comment: I totally agree that structs have their place, but that's why I said "in most cases, ..." -- in most cases, when a constructor takes "too many" arguments, it's a sign that the class is doing too much and could be refactored into smaller classes.

Comment: It can be that I was too hard. Sorry for that. "In most cases" sounded to me like "always with rare exceptions". "it's a sign that the class is doing too much" - yes, this can be a sign. Only before refactoring it is still necessary to make evaluation if this piece of code is the worst in the whole project or not. Most likely that other place needs more urgent attention.

Comment: No worries. Indeed I am somewhat of an OO purist, and when someone tags a question with "oop" or "design-patterns", I am naturally inclined to discuss the proper OO way rather than the quickest solution. :)

Comment: this method looks like "Parameter object pattern" and good option. similar discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551640/c-design-pattern-for-passing-a-large-number-of-parameters

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're describing is not a problem in C++ - in fact, C++ reflects the dependencies expressed by your design fairly well:

1. To construct an object of type `ClassA`, you need to have three `Object` instances (`a`, `b` and `c`).
2. To construct an object of type `ClassB`, you also need to have three `Object` instances (`d`, `e` and `f`).
3. Every object of type `ClassB` can be treated like an object of type `ClassA`.

This means that for constructing an object of type `ClassB` you need to provide three `Object` objects which are needed for the implementation of the `ClassA` interface, and then another three for the implementation of the `ClassB` interface.

I believe the *actual* issue here is your design. You could consider different approaches to resolve this:

1. Don't let `ClassB` inherit `ClassA`. May or may not be an option depending on whether you need homogenous access to objects of either type (say, because you have a collection of `ClassA*` and this collection could also contain pointers to `ClassB`).
2. Look for objects which always appear together. Like - maybe the first two objects passed to either constructor (`a` and `b` or `d` and `e`) represent some sort of pair. Maybe an object identifier or the like? In this case, it may be beneficial to introduce a dedicated abstract (read: type) for this.